# Cannot read property '__reactstandin__key' of undefined gatsby graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am new to gatsby and graphql.
Tried To get image with graphql, console is returning me image date, 
but next i get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactstandin__key' of undefined
```

Thats my code to get iamge:

```
export const fluidImage = graphql`
  fragment fluidImage on File {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
`

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    myPhoto: file(relativePath: { eq: "me.png" }) {
      ...fluidImage
    }
  }
`
```

in render

```
{console.log(this.props.data.myPhoto.childImageSharp.fluid)}
<Img fluid={this.props.data.myPhoto.childImageSharp.fluid} />
```

i get log with base64 data.
What can cause this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this error because I was using a named export instead of the default export.

**Do** use:

```
import Img from "gatsby-image"
```

**Do not** use:

```
import {Img} from "gatsby-image"
```